# How to increase lightSlider height irrespective of its content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can make the div height fit to screen by using:

```
.myDiv{

 position: fixed;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
         bottom: 0;
         right: 0;
         overflow: auto;
         background: lime; /* Just to visualize the extent */

}
```

When I try to use the same for the light slider, it did not work. Whatever the height I gave, the slider is taking the div content height , but not covering the whole screen.

Code for lightSlider:

```
<div data-role ="content">
            <ul id="light-slider">
               <li>
                    <div align="center">
                        <img src="img/Welcome to.png" width="100" height="10" />
                    </div>
                    <div align="center">
                        <img src="img/scrup.png" width="200" height="250" />
                    </div>
                    <div align="center">
                        <img src="img/Dots.png" width="80" height="10" />
                    </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
         </div>
```

Comment: even though i used fixed the div covers the whole screen but not the lightSlider. What can I try to make lightSlider to cover whole screen ?

Comment: I pasted the wrong code, I used fixed for div, and then I tried fixed, absolute,relative for the lightslider. It works for div, but none of those options worked for lightSlider.@freestock.tk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<div data-role ="content" class="a">
            <ul id="light-slider" class="a">
               <li>
                    <div align="center">
                        First div
                    </div>
                    <div align="center">
                        Second div
                    </div>
                    <div align="center">
                        Third div
                    </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
         </div>
<style>
.a{

 position: absolute;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
         bottom: 0;
         right: 0;
         background: lime; /* Just to visualize the extent */

}
</style>
```

As freestock commented, you need to have an absolute or fixed position. The green now covers the entire page, and the list dot is shown at the very corner. Also, you should remove the auto overflow.

Comment: green is covered entire page. But the list dots are shown at middle of screen which proves that slider  is not covering the whole screen.

Comment: when I use class=a for ul, the slider is pushed to very top, and the list dots are shown at the top of screen. Slider content is not shown in this case.

Comment: I only see 1 list dot at the top-left because it has only one entry within the list. That entry contains all three `div`s, and I did not set those `div`s to be part of the class `a`. What slider content do you want to be seeing?

Comment: I want the dots to be at the bottom of the screen, so that user gets the impression that slider is covering the full screen.

Comment: @V I am not quite sure what you mean. Do you want to fill the screen, but pin the list to the bottom?

Comment: THe list has 3 images. I call it as div1, div2 ,div 3. The last div is the image of dots. image height set as 10,250,10. This covers only a part of screen. I am now trying to increase the div height, so that images also fill the screen along with div. @StardustGogeta

Comment: @V You will need to do this yourself by replacing the placeholders I added, or provide the images to us. I do not have access to the image files to make an example.